# Spring Kafka retry not working as expected

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I configured a kafka template using Spring Kafka as follows:

```
@Bean
DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String> kafkaProducerFactory(KafkaProperties props) {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>(props.buildProducerProperties());

    configs.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configs.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configs, new StringSerializer(),
            new StringSerializer());
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("kafkaTemplate")
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String> kafkaProducerFactory) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(kafkaProducerFactory);
}
```

Then I configured a retry mechanism:

```
 spring.kafka.producer.retries=3
 spring.kafka.producer.properties.retry.backoff.ms=500
```

Finally, I called the producer:

```
kafkaTemplate.send(topic, "key", "PocEvent").get();
```

I'm pointing to a wrong port, so I would expect the producer to retry 3 times. But it doesn't! Did I forget something?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; those properties simply configure the underlying kafka-clients `KafkaProducer`. You generally will not see any retry activity at the Spring level. When a send actually fails depends on the failure reason. You need to describe in more detail what kind of send failure you are expecting.

Comment: I mean that in the log I only see the stacktrace for the TimeoutException once, but I would expect to see the exception being thrown 3 times instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I only see the stacktrace for the `TimeoutException` once

As I said in my comment, retries are performed within the kafka-clients library, Spring is not aware of them. We only get an exception after the retries have been exhausted (or some fatal exception occurs).

You won't see retries at the application level.

Comment: it looks like I had to set this: enable.idempotence=false but not sure why? Now I can see "Received invalid metadata error" message for the number of times expected and after that the excpetion stacktrace. Not sure why it works